# What is the best place to enqueueUniquePeriodicWork?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

I want to sync db with server data once a day, and what is the best place to enqueue the work, so it only runs once a day? WorkManager doesn't seem to care if the next enqueue call is within repeatInterval. If I put enqueueing work in Application class, and if that work is completed, WorkManager will run it again if I close and open the app.

Does it mean that I always have to check if the work is enqueued before calling `WorkManager.enqueue()`?

```
val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfosForUniqueWork("UNIQUE_WORK_NAME").get()?.getOrNull(0)
if (workInfo?.state == WorkInfo.State.ENQUEUED) {
    // do nothing
    return
}

workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "UNIQUE_WORK_NAME",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
                PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<SyncDbWorker>(
                        1,
                        TimeUnit.DAYS
                )
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build())
```

**UPDATE:**

One thing I forgot to mention is that inside my Worker I always return `Result.success()`. So if the work fails for some reason WorkManager will retry it on the next iteration.

Comment: Depends on the use case, but if you have a single activity app, use it there, else . use it only in the activity you need.

Comment: @StavroXhardha the thing is that it doesn't not belong to any activity, this work just has to be done once a day (fire and forget)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to check if the work is already enqueued when you use [`enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager#enqueueuniqueperiodicwork). Using `Keep` as `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy`, will guarantee that the work is only enqueued if there's no other work with the same `uniqueWorkName` already scheduled.

Said that, the usual place where you can enqueue your unique work is the `onCreate()` callback in your application. This will guarantee that the job is scheduled.

Keep in mind that a `PeriodicWorkRequest` can slips over time, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest.html). I've covered this in a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9r5OCb7Qb8) (around 24:25) I've presented last month with a possible workaround. Support for DailyWorkers is supposed to land in v2.1.x in one of the next alpha releases.

Comment: WorkManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork() does not seem to work in that way. Sometimes it ignores the interval when I kill and relaunch the app, at least on my emulators. Is it a bug?

Comment: I just found the answer to my problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129654588#comment2

Comment: There's nothing new in WorkManager at this moment for this. WorkManager doesn't support exact timing and the delays are relatives. To have a true "Daily Worker" we should need to consider also changes in the telephone timezone and that is not something we're working on. If you think this is important to have in the library, please file a Feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197

Comment: What is **DailyWorkers**??

Comment: I used the term `DailyWorker` to indicate a Worker that it is executed once a day always at the same time (e.g. a Worker that is executed each day at 6:00AM).

Comment: @pfmaggi Isn't AlarmManager the way to go for something that needs to be executed at a specific time, i.e. ExactTasks? Can't AlarmManager with `InexactRepeating` be used instead of DailyWorkers?

Comment: If you need to be executed at a specific time (e.g. 6AM), AlarmManager is the only API, on the device, available at this time. I personally think that a FCM from a server maybe a better option in this case (but it then depends if your task can be completed without connection, in that case FCM may not be the best). If you don't need an exact time, WorkManager is the best option as it covers a lot of corner cases and workarounds, like rescheduling workers after a Force Stop of your app on the first user launch. You will need to re-implement a lot of WorkManager to get similar capabilities.